# Prefuse freezes JFrame

Tags: java, visualization, prefuse

We are calling web services to gather information for a graph with about 1500 nodes.  We are displaying the graph in [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) while it continually is adding nodes and edges.  Most of the time this seems to work great, but every once in awhile the entire app freezes, and the only way to recover is to kill the application and start over.  No exceptions are printed out when this happens. On other occasions, I do fairly often see "IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row index: -1", but this doesn't seem to be associated with the freezing of the app.

I saw a related questions about [freezing in applets](http://sourceforge.net/projects/prefuse/forums/forum/343013/topic/1325782), but our app is running in a JFrame, not an applet.  Just in case this was our problem, we tried calling ActivityManager.stopThread() (could not find the kill method) in various places in our code.  This doesn't seem to have much if any difference.

Is there a thread safe way for [prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) to display the graph while editing the graph?

Comment: You probably need to show some code too.

Comment: Did you try calling `kill()` as recommended in that thread?

Comment: There is no longer a kill method.  I'm only guessing it has been replaced by stopThread().

Comment: @Viruzzo Good point.  I'll see if I can create a simple example that exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: @AndrewThompson it still would be better to find why it freezes and make it exit cleanly; stopping threads from another is not very clean.

Comment: For [`stopThread()`](http://prefuse.org/doc/api/prefuse/activity/ActivityManager.html#stopThread%28%29) the fine manual states *"Stops the activity manager thread. All scheduled actvities are canceled, and then the thread is then notified to stop running."*  Sounds like a good way to stop the activity, and with no mention of [`Thread.stop()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29). ;)  What happened when you tired calling it?

Comment: @JayAskren: You could try looking for EDT violation using one of the approaches cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7787998/230513).

Comment: Thanks trashgod.  That is a good point.  I have moved on to other things since I asked this question, but checking for EDT violations would have been useful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a thread safe way to display the graph while editing the graph?

All updates to the GUI must be done on the EDT. Use a SwingWorker.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Of course all updates to the gui must be on the EDT.  That doesn't help at all with debugging prefuse though.