# Java - repaint(x, y, w, h) doesn't call paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing, repaint, paintcomponent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - repaint(x, y, w, h) doesn't call paintComponent? (with SSCCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288127/java-repaintx-y-w-h-doesnt-call-paintcomponent-with-sscce)

I'm trying out this neato performance trick `repaint(x, y, w, h)` and it sure is helping performance a lot.

Unfortunately, the special extras I've put into a `paintComponent` in the same class are now not being painted.  I put a `System.out.println()` test at the beginning of `paintComponent` and it turns out it's not even called (as our astute readers probably were thinking from the beginning of this paragraph).  When I use a plain `repaint()`, `paintComponent()` is called, no problem.

Specifically, I've got a JLabel, with a `mouseListener`, that on `mouseEnter` repaints the label.

What's the deal?  I hope I'm missing something and this is still possible?  That extra performance sure is nice...

Comment: `... I hope I'm missing something... ` What you're missing is to add some code to your question so that we have half a prayer of being able to find your bug and help you. Best if you could create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288127/java-repaintx-y-w-h-doesnt-call-paintcomponent-with-sscce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repaint()` is actually a one-liner that calls `repaint(0, 0, width, height)`, so your basic thesis here -- that `repaint()` with arguments is fundamentally different from `repaint()` without -- is provably false. If I were a betting man, I'd bet that the arguments you're passing to this method describe a region with zero area (i.e., width <= 0) and so the `RepaintManager` is simply ignoring the requests.

You may be able to demonstrate this by changing the arguments to known good constant values, or maybe just `println()` the values of the arguments before you pass them.

Comment: +1 for the help - thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Actually did print out and got nonzero values for x, y, w, and h.  What I didn't get was an output in the actual paintComponent method...which leads me to my thesis :P

Comment: also - when I change the xy repaint to the plain repaint, the print in paintComponent does give an output.

Comment: also, again - what I'm mostly looking for is confirmation that "yes, the paintComponent method should be called under these circumstances" or "no, the dirty regions are assembled using paint" or something.

Comment: @Steve: there's no guarantee that paintComponent will be called for each call to the paint method, even if using the default method. The paint manager will queue the paint requests in the paint queue, but if the queue gets backed up, some painting will not be done.

Comment: @Hovercraft - interesting.  So would this be one of those never-do-this situations where paint() could/should be overridden?

Comment: @Steve: the only never-do that I get out of this is that program logic should never be in the paintComponent method, and for 3 reasons: 1) you aren't guaranteed 100% that paintComponent will be called when you desire, 2) it can often be called at the suggestion of the OS and under no control from you, and 3) you want no code in paintComponent that is unrelated to painting and that could slow it down. For more on this, check out: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/)

Comment: I've read that a bunch of times :/  and there isn't any logic in paintComponent, just painting.  The problem is, that painting isn't painting.  Anyway I'll go hack it out myself with the tips here, at that point can SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [JComponent#paintImmediately](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

1) be sure by testing your output to the Swing GUI by using / wrapping to the

```
if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
```

otherwise you could get an [exception from RepaintManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787998/how-to-generate-exceptions-from-repaintmanager)

2) `repaint()` could be invoke EDT by default, untill first `Thread#sleep(int)` called

3) invoke code for painting from [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and output will be on EDT, but Timer doesn't works too if `Thread#sleep(int)` called

Comment: Thanks mKorbel but actually solved in a duplicate question.  Mods haven't granted my request to delete this question yet.  Have a +1 for the trouble though. :)