# Java - repaint(x, y, w, h) doesn't call paintComponent? (with SSCCE)

Tags: java, swing, paint, repaint, paintcomponent

I asked this before, but only theoretically, without an SSCCE.  Now, I've created one, and the problem persists.  I'd like to know why `paintComponent` is not called on `repaint(x, y, w, h)`, but is called on `repaint()`.

Two classes:

**SANDBOX**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Add label
        f.getContentPane().add(new TLabel());

        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and **TLabel** (with a little styling):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TLabel extends JLabel {
    public TLabel() {
    super("TEST LABEL, NON-STATIC");
    this.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    TLabel.this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
    TLabel.this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
    TLabel.this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 50));

    TLabel.this.setOpaque(true);
    TLabel.this.setBackground(Color.cyan.darker().darker());
    TLabel.this.setForeground(Color.white);
    TLabel.this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.orange, 2));

    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // EXPECTED BEHAVIOR HERE: This line will call paint and paintComponent.
                //repaint();

                // PROBLEM HERE: This line will not call paint or paintComponent.
                repaint(TLabel.this.getBounds());
        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // Note: This is called once when the label is realised.
    // Note: This is called when the mouse enters the frame.
    System.out.println("PAINT.");
    super.paint(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // Note: This is called once when the label is realised.
    // Note: This is called when the mouse enters the frame.
    System.out.println("REPAINT.");
    super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling this

```
repaint(TLabel.this.getBounds());
```

inside of the TLabel object. So repaint will try to paint a rectangle located relative to itself at the Bounds location, but getBounds() returns a rectangle located relative to this components **containing object's location** while repaint expects bounds relative to the component itself.  So you're trying to paint a rectangle that has the width and height of your JLabel but which is located at x = 292 and y = 5 ***relative to the JLabel***, when instead you want x and y to both be 0. In essence you're trying to draw way outside of this component.

Instead try this:

```
        //!! repaint(TLabel.this.getBounds());
        Dimension d = TLabel.this.getSize();
        repaint(new Rectangle(0, 0, d.width, d.height));
```

Comment: +1 or (required in the EDT) paintImmediately http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: That's the trick - store the size outside of the call!  I was using getLocationOnScreen() also, but to no avail.

Comment: Maybe you could put a note to this question here at my last, duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287194/java-repaintx-y-w-h-doesnt-call-paintcomponent...I asked for the mods to delete but request was denied (or ignored).  Either way, arrivals at that question will want to be directed here - plus another accept for you :)