# Exception thrown in SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I am trying to use a `SwingWorker` in the `importData(..)` method from the `TransferHandler` class (to support drag and drop). I want to show the import progress of the files that I dragged. However, it does not work. I don't understand what the problem is, or what causing it.

```
private class FileImportTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean importData(JComponent comp, final Transferable t) {

        SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                //When commenting this code it and everything else it doesn't
                DataFlavor[] flavors = t.getTransferDataFlavors(); //<---- throws exception 
                //..more code that doesn't run.
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                super.done();

                try {
                    get();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ImportBeanController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ImportBeanController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
       //Starting worker etc here.
    }       
}
```

Exception:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)   at
>   javax.swing.SwingWorker.get(SwingWorker.java:582)     at
>   com.jatech.app.controllers$ImportBeanController$1.done(ImportBeanController.java:158)
>     at javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(SwingWorker.java:717)  at
>   javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(SwingWorker.java:814)
>     at sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(AccumulativeRunnable.java:95)
>     at
>   javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(SwingWorker.java:824)
>     at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:291)    at
>   javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:221)     at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer.getTransferDataFlavors(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:176)
>     at
>   sun.awt.datatransfer.TransferableProxy.getTransferDataFlavors(TransferableProxy.java:48)
>     at
>   java.awt.dnd.DropTargetContext$TransferableProxy.getTransferDataFlavors(DropTargetContext.java:327)

Comment: _What does the exception say?_

Comment: which exception? Anyway, more context needed - please show an SSCCE

Comment: @Dude your code in doInBackground threw a NullPointerException. Without that exception and the corresponding code, nobody will be able to help you more. Looks like you are still accessing AWT-DND info in your doInBackground--> do that before creating your SwingWorker and only perform the import operation within the SwingWorker#doInBackground()

Answer (score 3):

- you don't have got refference to the `SwingWorker` and whatever is/are invoked from `doInBackground()`
- please read answer by [@trashgod to my question about similair issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7054627/714968)
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), because maybe there are another issue with FileIO (you can to generate File on fly to \temp),
- [I found two - three another issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787998/how-to-generate-exceptions-from-repaintmanager), maybe Bug, maybe not, solved by `paintImmediately()`