# Display tooltip with object name and method associated using reflection?

Tags: java, swing, debugging, reflection, tooltip

I'd like to add an extra feature to the debug mode of the programme I've taken over.

What I want to be able to do add tooltips to all the buttons, tables  on the GUI so that they display something like this in them:

```
Class:  JButton
Name:   myShineyButton
Method: myShineyButtonActivateMethod
```

I know the general form for using reflection of this is like so:

```
for(Fields bits: this.GetClass().getDeclaredFields){
    if(bits instanceof Component){
        String methodName = bits.getMethod().toString();
        ....
    }
}
```

But then how do I add the tooltip to each item on the gui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into an [aspect-oriented programming (AOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) tool, such as [`AspectJ`](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/). You can examine/modify an object [after returning](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/faq.php#q:adviseconstructors) from a call to its constructor. As a concrete example, this [aspect](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/02/debugging_swing.html), cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7787998/230513), detects all [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) rule violations. More examples may be found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/sample-code.html).