# JRuby/Java Swing Tooltip Overlapping Window frame slows display to 4 Hz

Tags: java, performance, swing, tooltip, jruby

We are building/maintaining a complex motion-control-platform control application with 14 subsystems, each with its own thread, including several animated 2D or 3D windows.  Legacy requirements mandate JRuby 1.5.2 running on top of Java jre6 jdk1.6.0_21 with Java3D 1.5.2, on top of Windows (XP or 7).

When a Java Swing tooltip popup in one of the 2D control-panel windows, null Layout, overlaps & falls outside the bottom edge or sometimes the right edge of the window, the overall Windows Java screen update rate (for all the windows) slows from 16 Hz to 4 Hz. Often this effect continues until one of the windows is resized.  Sometimes this effect goes away when the tooltip disappears.  Occasionally the effect doesn't occur at all.

This occurs both on 32-bit Windows XP and 64-bit Windows 7, pointing more towards Java.  There are other amusing bugs where the Windows sleep clock actually speeds up when random unrelated third-party communications applications are running, but I think that's a red herring--this one's definitely a Java + Windows windows-layout bug. Best guess is Windows can't handle Java's resizing the effective window area rapidly?  But then why would the effect continue even after the tooltip popup goes away?

One source reports improvements with ensuring that all tooltips are "wider than 150 pixels".  It is one workaround, although: since the mechanism for the bug is not known, and the bug is stochastic, this helpful voodoo does not seem to guarantee a solution; as well, it precludes short tooltips.

Does anyone know WHY this combination of JRuby/Java/Swing/Windows is having problems with tooltips, and what can be done about it seriously?

Comment: please whats reason to use frequency under latency in native os, I'm think >= 25-33

Comment: these are actual measurements from what the Java is really doing, not what we set.  However, in a real-time control system with a simple basic '70s-style 2D button control panel, there is no reason to refresh this past 16Hz, and this certainly adds a safety margin for the system load.  The scrolling oscilloscope is still OK at 16Hz.  When Java gives us 4Hz the oscilloscope is fairly unacceptable, though.

Comment: agree, by deafult there no issue on Win8, but most of users (as you mentioned Win7/32) runs on Win7(corporate platform) / XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attaching a [profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to the running application may offer some insight, but *stochastic* failure often implies incorrect synchronization. *All* Swing GUI objects *must* be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). To find violations, use one of the approaches cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7787998/230513). The `ToolTipManager` tries to use a lightweight component to display tooltips. If your application mixes light- and heavy-weight components, you can try disabling the feature:

```
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this excellent answer.  We tried the ToolTipManager hack and it did not work for us.  Running Swing in the event dispatch thread is the right answer.  However, for practical reasons it is not feasible for us to rewrite three legacy graphic control managers into the master dispatch thread.  We ended up going with the 150 pixel restriction, about 2"+ or roughly six+ words at normal resolution.  So far this is working.  Thank you again.