# JComponent InputMap mysteriously getting wiped

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, keyboard-events, jcomponent

I've added bindings to a `JComponent`'s input map, by modifying the map returned by `jCompInstance.getInputMap()`.

The *first* time I hit a key which I've binded, it works fine. Somehow, thereafter, the `InputMap` gets wiped. What I mean by this is `jCompInstance.getInputMap().size()` returns `0`.

I apologise for not offering a minimalistic code example which reproduces the problem; attempts to reduce my huge program have been futile.

What might be going on here?

Is there a way for me to set a watchpoint (in Eclipse) of the `JComponent`'s internal `InputMap` to investigate how this may be occurring?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A failed attempt to reproduce the problem is frustrating, but always worthwhile: it implies that your essential approach to [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) is likely sound, and a reference example will guide your search for the problem.

Recall that each component's UI delegate is responsible for establishing its key bindings. At a guess, you might check several related things:

- Ensure that Swing GUI objects are constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) in the desired order, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7787998/230513).
- Verify correct use of `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()`; in particular, don't use it as a substitute for `validate()`.
- In a custom component, override `updateUI()` to apply any custom bindings, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137801/230513) for colors.