# mysql sqlExceptiion Error

Tags: java, mysql, swing, sqlexception

I will begin by saying that I googled the problem and found explanation but still can not fix the error...:s
I'm getting `java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after`ResultSet`closed` (what I understand is that I should create a new statement and new `ResultSet` and like said still can't make it work - if that is now right way of thinking)
would appreciate all the help.

```
public class IdPanel extends JPanel {

    private JLabel idLabel;
    private JTextField idField;
    private JButton okBtn;
    private JButton newEmployeBtn;
    private NewEmployeDialog newEmployeDialog;

    private Connection myConn;
    private Statement myStmt;
    private ResultSet myRs;

    public IdPanel() throws SQLException {

        idLabel = new JLabel("ID:");
        idField = new JTextField(12);
        okBtn = new JButton("OK");
        newEmployeBtn = new JButton("New Employe...");

        myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://*********", ********);
        myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from employe");

        try {
            newEmployeDialog = new NewEmployeDialog();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            System.out.println("check IdPanel-->NewEmployeDialog");
        }

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setGc();

        okBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String id = idField.getText();
                try {
                    while (myRs.next()) {
                        String idImp = myRs.getString(1);
                        if (id.equals(idImp)) {
                            System.out.println(id);

                            try {
                                myStmt.executeUpdate("update employe set phone =99321 where id=346");
                            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        idField.setText("");
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        myConn.close();
        myStmt.close();
        myRs.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `myRs` in your `ActionListener`, but `myRs` has already been closed.

Swing is an event driven enviroment, by the time the `ActionListener` is notified of the `ok` button's event, the `close` statements have already been executed

Instead of creating the connection and exciting the query in the main block, move it to the `AdtionListener`

I'd also encourage you to use `PreparedStatement`s, see [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

```
okBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String id = idField.getText();
        try (Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://*********",  * * * * * * * *)) {
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = myConn.prepareStatement("update employe set phone=? where id=?")) {
                stmt.setInt(1, 99321);
                stmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(id));
                stmt.executeUpdate()
                idField.setText("");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Also take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for better resource management ideas

Comment: Perffect -thank you for help, explenation (event driven enviroment) and tips (prepared Statements) (y)

Comment: idField.setText(""); should be always inside invokeLater, doesn't matter for Java4/5 probably :-)

Comment: @mKorbel Why? It's within the context of the `ActionListener` which is called from within the EDT...

Comment: you are still in risk that after 15/20(max -30) seconds your EDT go away in Java7/8, doesn't matter if is called from Listener with reason to freeze (intentionally) GUI, I think that series of bugs in Java6 reason for SecondaryLoop is there in Java7,

Comment: @mKorbel How can the EDT go away, when the code is been executed within it's context?  Is this a deadlock feature?

Comment: I'm think that is about exceptionhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053865/cant-get-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-from-future-and-swingworker-if-threa from RepaintManagerhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787998/how-to-generate-exceptions-from-repaintmanager, very long NIO, and every JDBC, XxxSocket, ... are reasons for short_cuts as are SwingWorker (my view is that is sloppy,simple tacky), and later with SecondaryLoop implemented in official APIs

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the Statement and ResultSet code into the `actionPerformed` method. Right now you open a result set and immediately close it, then try to use it at a later time, in the ActionListener. You should also use PreparedStatements and proper error handling, like so:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("...") {
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("...");
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        /* Parse result */
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    for (Throwable t : ex) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```