# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 in Swing's JTree

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception, jtree, jtreetable

Here is the exception i am getting, when i am trying to save the first value of  `int[]` to a simple primitive. The array is part of a `JTree`.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

I studied other topics for a while now and mostly found the answer, that logically my array has to be empty. But it is not! Other references to multidimensional arrays and vectors also play no role.

```
private void paintSelectionRect() {

    // Get selected row bounds:
    System.out.println("Test "+tree.getSelectionRows()[0]); // Output: Test
    System.out.println("Size "+tree.getSelectionRows().length); // Output: Size 1

    if (tree.getSelectionRows() == null) {
        selectedRowBounds = null;
        return;
    }

    int row = tree.getSelectionRows()[0]; // Exception!

    selectedRowBounds = tree.getRowBounds(row);
    // Repaint the JTree:
    tree.repaint();
}
```

So, the value of the first entry is 4 and the only entry made (size 1). Also, it can not be null. So why is `System.out.println()` able to read, but a reference to the `int` can not be made?

Always when I select a row from the tree, it is saved during the first click in `MouseEvent`. The method is called after a `TreeSelectionListener` was added.

```
TreeSelectionModel selectionModel = tree.getSelectionModel();

    selectionModel.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {

         public void valueChanged(final TreeSelectionEvent e) {
            paintSelectionRect();
        }
    });

    tree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            int row = tree.getClosestRowForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());

            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                if (tree.isCollapsed(row)) {
                    tree.expandRow(row);
                } else {
                    tree.collapseRow(row);
                }
            } else {
                tree.setSelectionRow(row);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Just edited and hope it now will be less confusing.

Comment: "My array has to be empty, but it is not!" Look for EDT violations, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7787998/230513).