# Java (error) message when using undocumented matlab function "uitree"

Tags: java, matlab, swing, awt

I have setup a Matlab-function which uses the undocumented Matlab function "uitree". "uitree" exists yet since more than 10 years and is still (R2016b) "offered" by MATLAB to be used. I used the return value (handle) of "uitree" with some simple "java" functions for adding and removing tree-nodes during execution of my m-function.

But when processing one very big file (which I use for regression testing of my m-function) with my m-function I get the following (error) message, which is displayed in red color in the Matlab command window. This message does only appear sporadically, let's say when I process the same big file 10 times it occurs 1 time. And the message is exactly the same, also the numbers are 245 and 241.

This message does not cause any error within MATLAB and I didn't see any anomaly in the results of processing the big file, but I would like to understand what is the cause and what I can do to avoid it. Unfortunately due to reasons above (sporadic and doesn't cause any error) I had no luck when trying to add breakpoints and display messages to find the location. And unfortunately also that I am not at all familiar with Java, Swing and Awt :-(.

In difference to the similar question already raised "[What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)" in my case it is occuring sporadic, so the message comes occasionally with one and the same file being processed.

Can anybody give me some hint, what it could be and what I can do else to find the cause of the problem?

#### Java Message displayed in MATLAB command window

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 245 >= 241
at java.util.Vector.removeElementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache$TreeStateNode.collapse(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache$TreeStateNode.collapse(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.setExpandedState(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.treeCollapsed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTree.fireTreeCollapsed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTree.setExpandedState(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTree.collapsePath(Unknown Source)
at com.mathworks.hg.peer.UITreePeer$4.run(UITreePeer.java:221)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here an overview of related m-functions and Java-functions that are used:

#### Undocumented MATLAB functions used:

```
hTree = uitree
jTree = hTree.Tree
hTreeNode = uitreenode
```

`hTree`     being of class: `javahandle_withcallbacks.com.mathworks.hg.peer.UITreePeer`

`jTree`     being of class: `javahandle_withcallbacks.com.mathworks.hg.peer.utils.UIMJTree`

`hTreeNode` being of class: `javahandle.com.mathworks.hg.peer.UITreeNode`

#### Java/MATLAB functions used:

I don't know exactly what comes directly from Java and what is something in the interface between Java/MATLAB and implemented by MATLAB ... code snippets

```
% For Tree Context Menu
hJTree= handle(jTree, 'CallbackProperties');
hJTree.MousePressedCallback= {@guiCallback_tree_mousePressed,sessionNum};

% ...

% Cell renderer ... Get a dummy color definition
bsc= jTree.getCellRenderer.getBackgroundSelectionColor;
jTree.getCellRenderer.setBackgroundSelectionColor(bsc.lightGray);
jTree.getCellRenderer.setBorderSelectionColor(bsc.lightGray);

% ...

treePath= jTree.getSelectionPath.getPath;
for i=2:length(treePath)
   lable= char(treePath(i).getValue);
end
```

#### Further Java functions used:

`hTreeNode`

- `add, getChildCount, getChildAt, getValue, getLevel, getParent, setName, repaint`

`hTree`

- `Position, NodeSelectedCallback, expand, collapse`
- `getModel` using `insertNodeInto, removeNodeFromParent`

`jTree`

- `isExpanded, setSelectionPath, isPathSelected, scrollPathToVisible`
- all called with argument `javax.swing.tree.TreePath("pathnode")`

Comment: I have added a statement why my question is different than the similar one already answered

Comment: Words like _sporadic_ always make me think of [_incorrect synchronization_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html); diagnostics cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7787998/230513).

Comment: I agree, but Matlab is not threaded from a user point of view, and I all I do is calling m-functions (and add/remove node Java functions) one after the other. I already added "pauses" of 30ms after issuing a Java command to give "Java" time to refresh the tree, before issuing another Java command but it didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, either MATLAB _does_ run on the event dispatch thread, thus blocking it, or MATLAB does _not_ run on the event dispatch thread, thus requiring synchronization.

Comment: The latter is the case, but MATLAB doesn't care at all about synchronisation of user-called Java objects. And myself as a simple user, which does not know anything about Java and synchronisation, only wanting a "tree" in a MATLAB figure to add nodes and remove nodes is overstrained with these tasks ... may be also a reason why this undocumented function will remain undocumented. To come back, all I know I can do from MATLAB side is using "pauses".

Comment: @Domenico Are you calling any java methods directly? If so you can call them from [within the EDT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javamethodedt.html)

Comment: @Suever, a list of used functions have been added to the original post. I tried to understand the linked MATLAB EDT-function but I did not succeed.

Comment: @Domenico, you should [read this](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-and-the-event-dispatch-thread-edt)