# How t find eventqueue opertion elapsed time and How to find which UI operation causes lags

Tags: java, swing, eventqueue

In Java Swing application, How to find which event queue operation makes delay and freezes Ui and the cause. Since may invokeLater() are called to perform Ui Operation. 
Is there any way to get the elapsed time too.  ( by tracing eventQueue ex: like a class  SampleTrackingUserEvents extends EventQueue{ ... }

As a golden rule, avoided IO operation and sleep, But even after a long run for 8 hrs. the Ui get unresponsive for few seconds. How to find the elapsed time and which Ui operation caused this.

Need help.

Comment: by default nothing can make a delay, nor to freeze the GUI, something must be executed from EDT, all threads can be recorded from JProfiler

Comment: This happens in webstart at rare occurrences and hard to see UI lags for 5 - 20 sec randomly. running jprofiler is not good enough to track since Is slow down the process by hooking the live objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How to generate exceptions from RepaintManager*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7787998/230513).

Comment: The problem not with Ui Violation. the UI lags for 10 secons.                            
java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method) java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source) java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source) java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(Unknown Source)
  com.sun.deploy.security.JarVerifier.readAndMaybeSaveStreamTo(Unknown Source)